# ShopifyAPI::FulfillmentService returns empty list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am building an Shopify app. When a user installs the app on his shop, I need to get the list of fulfilment services that are active on his shop, mainly the amazon marketplace web. 
The app uses `ShopifyAPP` and `ShopifyAPI` gems, so I tried to call
`ShopifyAPI::FulfillmentService.all`. but it returns an empty list. I tried it on two shops with different fulfillment services activated, and got the same results. I tried to set the scope to `'all'`, but got the same results as well.
Any idea how I can get the list of the fulfillments services?